# SendToBack seems to not work in Firemonkey?

Tags: forms, delphi, firemonkey, z-order

I'm working on Firemonkey application with a main form that contains a lot of controls on it. I want to create some more controls and send them to back using `SendToBack`. For some reason this does not work as expected. Controls are not being sent to full back, they stop short of 1 control.

Here's a sample setup:

- Create a new TForm.
- Place 3 Buttons on it, overlapping each other (Button1, Button2, Button3).
- In the runtime, call `Button3.SendToBack` - button goes back, but only by 1 position. Button1 still remains the backmost.

Inspecting TForm source code reveals that `SendToBack` calls `SendChildToBack`, which determines backmost location as:

```
function TCommonCustomForm.GetBackIndex: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;
```

should not it be 0?

Questions:

- Why does SendToBack send controls to "last but one" position instead of backmost? Is there a special reason for GetBackIndex returning 1?
- How do I send controls to back? Given that my form has a lot of controls and sending everything but needed controls to front with `BringToFront` would be undesireable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm creating own controls,

```
ctrl := TSomeControl.Create(aForm);
ctrl.Parent := aForm;
ctrl.SendToBack;
```

can be replaced with:

```
ctrl := TSomeControl.Create(aForm);
aForm.InsertObject(0 {desired index}, ctrl);
```